# Permitting answers that deviate from Jewish law and tradition

Tags: discussion

Can we rely on downvotes to out answers that are not based on Jewish law and tradition, as per this site's operational standards?  Isn't there a danger that a viewer will take an answer with six downvotes and no upvotes to simply be an unpopular but equally valid answer, and come to transgress?

If a poster is consistently answering based on their own opinions and speculations without any basis or grounding in any sort of Jewish tradition, can any actions be taken to prevent them from potentially leading people astray?

Somewhat related: [How should we handle pluralistic post?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/how-should-we-handle-pluralistic-posts)

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/how-should-we-handle-pluralistic-posts#comment3520_1298

Comment: @DoubleAA with regards to that, I think the assumption under which I'm working here is that an answer that is not sourced in Jewish law and tradition is by definition not a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think downvotes and comments give the otherwise unsuspecting reader a pretty good idea what's going on.  (I know that when I go to other SE sites looking for information I take votes into account; I don't think I'm uncommon in that.)  Flagging or voting for deletion (for those who have the rep) is also possible.

Comment: Answers with negative votes get grayed-out by the system. It’s farely obvious they are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if the answer is properly sourced, everyone knows where it's coming from, and it's no one's fault if someone doesn't do their own due diligence and ignores the stated source(s). If it isn't, it deserves to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

i'm upvoting your question because it's a legitimate question. But i agree with Dov F. i am probably a heavy posting user who gives answers that are not within traditional Judaism. Many times i source historical responses, but these responses often fall outside of "traditional Judaism." And i try to make that distinction clear in my answers in hopes that i don't lead anyone astray.

However, if someone tries to answer a question, pretending its in the jewish tradition, when it actually isn't, that's cause for concern

Comment: [Voting is different on meta.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) If you disagree, downvote, even if it's a legitimate question.