# Is Hellenistic Judaism on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Consensus on meta seems to be that [Karaite Judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1532/1569), questions asked from a [Karaite perspective](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4055/1569), and [other non-Orthodox branches of Judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1307/1569) are on-topic.

Is [Hellenistic Judaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic_Judaism) also on-topic?

Is such a question valid only for questions about the history of Judaism? Or are questions about explaining a Hellenistic Jewish text or language used in such a text also on-topic?

I ask because [LXX transliteration of יהושע](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91821/1569) was closed as off-topic (though arguably it could have been for other reasons). If Hellenistic Judaism is on-topic, then the Septuagint should also be on-topic without a doubt. Compare also [a question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11878/1569) about a word in Onkelos's translation, which is heavily upvoted and apparently considered on-topic.

Comment: אם-אלוהים הוא ירב לו.

Comment: that wiki article's list of claimed  hellenized Jews is ... interesting

Answer (score 2):

Since no one answered yet, I suggest:

- Questions about Judaism as practiced by Hellenistic Jews is on-topic whenever Judaism is considered on-topic
- Questions related to explaining Hellenistic Jewish texts are on-topic insofar as they relate to Judaism
- The same is true for texts of the Qumran community, Samaritans, and Jewish apocryphal texts
- Jewish Christianity is off-topic unless otherwise related to Judaism
- Answers from any of these perspectives are allowed only when specifically allowed for by the question