# How do I contact the moderators here?

Tags: discussion

How do I contact the moderators here? I often have my comments deleted. I have even had quotes from the Mishnah and Talmud deleted, and incorrectly tagged as "not answering the question" as a reason, even though the quotes were very specific answers. I am happy to follow the rules, and would like to find the Mi Yodeaya rules, and find our forum for discussion where moderators and contributors can discuss things like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81128/discussion-between---and-independentthinker).

Comment: Most of the questions you are interested in finding out the answers to can be found by searching on this website, "meta".  You will also notice a number of related questions on the right side.

Comment: I believe this question post addresses the same issues as the one I just maked it as a duplicate of. For more on what moderators do, see: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators Re: " Is this a Haredi only community?"  No. For more on this, read https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/is-there-not-room-for-non-orthodox-opinions and posts linked from there.

Comment: I would suggest familiarizing yourself with how this site works, particularly when it comes to posting answers. There are specific criteria for what makes something an answer. A post can be true and can contain quotes from the Mishnah and Talmud and still not be an answer. I saw four deleted answers of yours, and as far as I can tell they did not address the questions that were asked. That is probably why they were deleted. Note, that some of them were deleted by multiple people so it is unlikely that one moderator is harassing you.

Comment: These two links in particular should be helpful: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It can be a bit rough here until you understand how this site works. Most notably, this **not** a discussion forum, but a site for (hopefully) high-quality Q&As. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!