# Are non Halacha related questions permitted in this forum?

Tags: discussion

Are non Halacha related questions permitted in this forum ? Also are most answers coming from an orthodox point of view (regardless to the fact that my questions were oriented towards an orthodox point of view answer) ?

All of my questions so far have received a negative attitudes with followed comments being deleted, with negative votes on 3 consecutive questions in less than a minute (as if a user was punishing me), with one question even being closed. I am only a Jewish guy that wants to learn about his Jewish identity (culture and religion wise).

(Click here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/24841/isaac-brenig to see my questions)

What am I missing about this forum ?

(All the other stack exchange forums seem to be academically related, besides this one)

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/is-there-not-room-for-non-orthodox-opinions

Comment: @Joel k the answer to that question was started by citing the definition of this website: “ Jewish Life and Learning - Stack Exchange is for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more.” I am just a guy that wants to learn more!!!

Answer (score 5):

There is a high-level list of subjects in Mi Yodeya's scope on the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page of our Help Center:

> - Jewish law or practice (what to do or why)
> - Jewish philosophy
> - a Jewish text (explaining a passage)
> - history of Judaism
> - language used in Judaism
> - general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism

Only the first item on the list relates directly to Halacha. In practice, if you look around Mi Yodeya's tens of thousands of extant questions, you'll find that they, indeed, span these subjects.

The first line on the same page indicates the basic assumption of this community:

> Mi Yodeya is for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more.

That does not specify any specific denomination or community, but it does indicate that all answers will be from the point of view of *Judaism*. There are quite a few previous posts here on Meta regarding whether or not the only point of view allowed here is "Orthodox." Start with [this one](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/is-there-not-room-for-non-orthodox-opinions), and read posts linked to it. The short answer is "no."

The identity of a participant here should have no bearing on how content contributed by that participant is evaluated. Content should be (and generally is) evaluated based on how well it fits our scope and format, how interesting or useful it is to the reader, how clearly and engagingly it's written, etc.

One downvote indicates that one community member considered a post substandard along one or more of these axes, but presents an extremely limited view of the sense of the community.

Closure indicates that a question doesn't fit our scope or format in the specific way indicated in the closure notice. In many cases, the question can be edited to fit and then re-opened.

Comment: That is true but in many cases no matter how many times you edit the question, it will never satisfy an orthodox answer.

Comment: Thus avoiding a broader knowledge of Judaism

Comment: @IsaacBrenig It's not necessary. See e.g. the tag [reform-judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reform-judaism). Isaac Moses already wrote in this answer that Orthodox is not the only point of view allowed

Answer (score 2):

There are currently 8,331 tagged with [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha):

[image: Screenshot showing tag statistics]

The site as a whole has some 34,000 questions:

[image: Screenshot showing site statistics]

Seemingly, then, a great majority of questions are not about halacha.

Comment: Or are simply not tagged Halacha

Comment: Probably some. But unlikely 20,000+.

Comment: @Aled though not reflected based on judging the home page

Comment: @Isaac check out [tag:parshanut-torah-comment]

Comment: @Double AA how does orthodox parshanut represent broader Judaism related studies ?

Comment: @Isaac huh? You asked in this thread about the permissibility of non-halacha questions. I linked to a bunch.

Comment: @Alex based on the first few pages following the home page on this site, most non halachic questions seem to be very hesitant

Comment: @Double AA according to orthodoxy parshanut becomes Halacha and these questions are mostly non debated - they were debated and we can learn about these debates, but we can not debate them

Comment: @IsaacBrenig I’ve asked 62 questions on this site, most not about halacha. All but one have a positive score.

Comment: @Alex I have gone through your questions which are wonderful questions but many aren’t necessarily discussing  Judaism but rather technical user questions

Comment: @Alex your profile shows 32 questions you might want to update it

Comment: @IsaacBrenig I think you are looking at my Meta site profile where I indeed have 32 questions that are technical user questions. On the main site, however, I have 62 questions, all about Judaism, most not about halacha.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to spend more time browsing Mi Yodeya. There are many non-halachic questions, but most have a Torah basis. Answers are from an Orthodox point of view. Many questions remain unanswered if they are poorly written, or too specific, etc.

Comment: I have upvoted the question since it has answered my question, however I am personally disappointed by the answer, since my personal opinion is that Judaism is more than just Halacha . However I better understand what questions are permitted in this forum now.

Comment: I also must mention that this forum doesn’t really comply with the stack exchange philosoph which is more academically related .

Comment: It's not always the case that answers are from an orthodox point of view, though it usually is.

Comment: @DoubleAA It also depends on how exactly you define the Orthodox point of view. I’m sure I (probably you as well) have posted some things that some Orthodox Jews would object to.

Comment: @Alex it's hard to name a rabbi who hasn't said something someone objected to...

Comment: @DoubleAA True, though of course not all objections are “this isn’t Orthodox”.

Comment: @IsaacBrenig You are right in general, but forums have tendencies that have to be respected.